# ADSI/System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher result parsing

Tags: powershell, adsi

A trivial question, but hopefully really obvious for those who know.

Search constructor:

```
$Search = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
(([adsi]"LDAP://ou=Domain Users,dc=example,dc=pri"),'(objectCategory=person)',
('name','employeeID'))
```

I want to exclude results where the employeeID attribute does not exist.

This works:

```
$users = $Search.FindAll()
ForEach ($u in $users) {
    If ($u.properties.employeeid) {
        Write-Host $($u.properties.name)
    }
}
```

The following does not work - no output. However, when the IF statement is omitted, results are output.

```
ForEach ($user in $($Search.FindAll())) {
    If ($user.properties.employeeID) {
        Write-Host $($user.properties.name)
    } 
}
```

Is it a syntax issue in the second example, or do I just need to temporarily store results in an object before running conditional statements on them?

(To circumvent any discussion on why not use the ActiveDirectory module and Get-ADUser, it's for a user that cannot have the module installed on their workstation, nor be granted perms to invoke it via a PSSession on a host where it is installed.)

**Update:** found a slightly nicer way of doing the `where` clause:

```
$searcher.FindAll() | where { ($_.properties['employeeid'][0]) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `if` statement and filter search results:

```
$users = $Search.FindAll() | Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.properties.employeeID)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, and it's much nicer to do it as a filter.